# Accessing objects inside an object for a list

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, javascript-objects

So I have this object which has other objects and array nested inside it. I want to create a function that lists all the elements in this object and its nested objects. I did create a function but when it lists the items in the objects, it shows [object object] on the section where there is a nested object or array

This is the object that I have :

```
let weather = {
        base: "stations",
        clouds: {
          all: 1
        },
        coord: {
          lat: 43.65,
          lon: -79.38
        },
        dt: 1507510380,
        id: 6167863,
        main: {
          humidity: 77,
          pressure: 1014,
          temp: 17.99,
          temp_max: 20,
          temp_min: 16
        },
        name: 'Downtown Toronto',
        sys: {
          type: 1,
          id: 2117,
          message: 0.0041,
          country: 'CA',
          sunrise: 1507548290,
          sunset: 1507589027,
          type: 1
        },
        visibility: 16093,
        weather: [
          {
            description: 'clear sky',
            icon: '01n',
            id: 800,
            main: "Clear"
          }
        ],
        wind: {
          deg: 170,
          speed: 1.5
        }
      
      }
```

Function that i created :

```
function listWeather(object) {
        let itemsList = ''
        for (let key in object) {
          itemsList+= '<li>' + key + ' : ' + object[key] + '</li>'
        }
        return itemsList
      }
```

Comment: You're not currently doing anything to handle the nested-ness; did you intend to write a recursive function?

Comment: Yes i wanted a recursive function. Im not sure of how to write the function to handle the nested elements and array

Comment: You already have it--you just need to decide how you want to handle the nesting and how fancy you want the output to be (and how you'll determine if an object value is an object/array). Very roughly, with no thought to... well, anything: https://jsfiddle.net/davelnewton/p9ezyd1v/

Comment: Noting that IRL you'd likely want to split out how each object key data is handled, order things differently, and so on--while it's a simple recursive function on the surface, it's unlikely that a simplistic approach is viable. It's much more likely you'd need to handle each key in specific ways, e.g., to skip display, format output like sunrise/sunset times, and so on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
let weather = {
    base: "stations",
    clouds: {
      all: 1
    },
    coord: {
      lat: 43.65,
      lon: -79.38
    },
    dt: 1507510380,
    id: 6167863,
    main: {
      humidity: 77,
      pressure: 1014,
      temp: 17.99,
      temp_max: 20,
      temp_min: 16
    },
    name: 'Downtown Toronto',
    sys: {
      type: 1,
      id: 2117,
      message: 0.0041,
      country: 'CA',
      sunrise: 1507548290,
      sunset: 1507589027,
      type: 1
    },
    visibility: 16093,
    weather: [
      {
        description: 'clear sky',
        icon: '01n',
        id: 800,
        main: "Clear"
      }
    ],
    wind: {
      deg: 170,
      speed: 1.5
    }
  
  }

function listWeather(object) {
    let itemsList = ''
    let itemsSubList = ''
    for (let key in object) {
      var item = object[key]
      if( isObject(item) ){
        for (let k in item) {
        document.write('<li>---' + k + ' : ' + item[k] + '</li>');
        }
      }else{
        if( Array.isArray(item) ){
          document.write('<li>----'+ key +':</li>');
          for (let l in item[0]) {
            document.write('<li>------' + l + ' : ' + item[0][l] + '</li>');
          }
        }else{
          document.write('<li>' + key + ' : ' + object[key] + '</li>');
        }
      }
    }
    // return itemsList
 }

function isObject(objValue) {
  return objValue && typeof objValue === 'object' && objValue.constructor === Object;
}

listWeather(weather)
```

Comment: This is what you are trying to achieve, and based on your given object "weather" we have to use functions to identify the values inside the nested objects and array.